# Ajax DataTable not showing values for field names containing dots (.)

Tags: ajax, datatables

My ajax DataTable response is like this but it is not showing fieldname value in browser.

I am using Laravel as backend. My ajax DataTable is not showing field name like `brands.name` value, means if the field name contains a `.` then it is not showing value.

```
{
        "draw": 1,
        "iTotalRecords": 4,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 4,
        "aaData": [{
            "models.id": 2,
            "brands.name": "Maruti",
            "models.name": "Maruti",
            "action": "<a class=\"tp\" title=\"Edit\" href=\"http:\/\/localhost\/cnp1352\/admin\/make-and-model\/Mg==\/edit\"><i class='fa fa-edit'><\/i><\/a>\n<a  title=\"Soft Delete\" data-id=\"Mg==\" data-table=\"bW9kZWxz\" class='delete tp' href='javascript:void(0);'><i\n            class='fa fa-trash-alt'><\/i><\/a>\n"
        }, {
            "models.id": 2,
            "brands.name": "Maruti",
            "models.name": "Maruti",
            "action": "<a class=\"tp\" title=\"Edit\" href=\"http:\/\/localhost\/cnp1352\/admin\/make-and-model\/Mg==\/edit\"><i class='fa fa-edit'><\/i><\/a>\n<a  title=\"Soft Delete\" data-id=\"Mg==\" data-table=\"bW9kZWxz\" class='delete tp' href='javascript:void(0);'><i\n            class='fa fa-trash-alt'><\/i><\/a>\n"
        }, {
            "models.id": 1,
            "brands.name": "Honda",
            "models.name": "Honda",
            "action": "<a class=\"tp\" title=\"Edit\" href=\"http:\/\/localhost\/cnp1352\/admin\/make-and-model\/MQ==\/edit\"><i class='fa fa-edit'><\/i><\/a>\n<a  title=\"Soft Delete\" data-id=\"MQ==\" data-table=\"bW9kZWxz\" class='delete tp' href='javascript:void(0);'><i\n            class='fa fa-trash-alt'><\/i><\/a>\n"
        }, {
            "models.id": 1,
            "brands.name": "Honda",
            "models.name": "Honda",
            "action": "<a class=\"tp\" title=\"Edit\" href=\"http:\/\/localhost\/cnp1352\/admin\/make-and-model\/MQ==\/edit\"><i class='fa fa-edit'><\/i><\/a>\n<a  title=\"Soft Delete\" data-id=\"MQ==\" data-table=\"bW9kZWxz\" class='delete tp' href='javascript:void(0);'><i\n            class='fa fa-trash-alt'><\/i><\/a>\n"
        }]
    }
```

My data table initialization is like the following:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
    
        var dataTableSettings = {};
    
        dataTableSettings.autoWidth = false;
        dataTableSettings.order = [
            [0, "desc"]
        ];
    
        dataTableSettings.aLengthMenu = [
            ["10", "20", "30", "-1"],
            ["10", "20", "30", "all"]
        ];
    
        dataTableSettings.dom = '<"pull-left"f> Br <"pull-right"l>tip';
        // dataTableSettings.dom='Blfrtip';
        dataTableSettings.buttons = [];
        // dataTableSettings.fixedColumns= true;
    
    
        dataTableSettings.processing = true;
        dataTableSettings.serverSide = true;
        dataTableSettings.paging = true;
        dataTableSettings.ajax = {};
    
    
    
        dataTableSettings.ajax.url = "http://localhost/cnp1352/admin/make-and-model";
        dataTableSettings.ajax.data = function(data) {
    
            $(".search-form input, .search-form  select ").each(function() {
                data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    
            });
        };
        dataTableSettings.columns = [{
            "data": "models.id"
        }, {
            "data": "brands.name"
        }, {
            "data": "models.name"
        }, {
            "data": "action"
        }];
        dataTableSettings.columnDefs = [
    
            {
                "targets": [3],
                "orderable": false,
            },
            {
                "visible": false,
                "targets": []
            },
    
            {
                "targets": [],
                "createdCell": function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                    $(td).addClass("img-custom-product");
                }
            }
    
    
        ];
    
    
    
    
        dataTableSettings.language = {
            paginate: {
                previous: "<i class='mdi mdi-chevron-left'>",
                next: "<i class='mdi mdi-chevron-right'>"
            },
            info: "Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_"
        };
    
        dataTableSettings.drawCallback = function() {
            $(".dataTables_paginate > .pagination").addClass("pagination-rounded")
        };
    
        table = $('#empTable').DataTable(dataTableSettings);
        $('#empTable_filter input').addClass('form-control');
        $('#empTable_length select').addClass('form-control');
        var info = table.page.info();
    
    
     });
```

But output is showing like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

DataTables uses JavaScript's dotted notation to [drill down into nested JSON structures](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/deep). And, as you have seen, this conflicts with JSON keys which themselves have dots in their names, such as `"brands.name"`.

The solution is to place these names inside square brackets:

```js
dataTableSettings.columns = [
  { "data": ["models.id"] }, 
  { "data": ["brands.name"] }, 
  { "data": ["models.name"] }, 
  { "data": "action" }
];
```

Now, Datatables will use JavaScript bracket notation, instead of dotted notation for these items.

See [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) for background.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that.